# File remains locked despite unlocking

Tags: c#, file, file-locking

Why am I receiving an IOException when I come to delete this file? Surely I have unlocked it? Apparently another process is still using the file, despite not touching it otherwise.

```
using (var lockFile = new FileStream(lockFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
{
    try
    {
        var productCount = downloadStuff();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        lockFile.Unlock(0,lockFile.Length);
        File.Delete(lockFilePath);
    }

}
```

Comment: Try running it without being in `Debug` mode.   The host process for Visual Studio' s debugger has a terrible habit of hanging on to file locks even after your code lets it go.

Comment: @user1895086 so how can I debug it otherwise! And just tried running a debug build of the application outside the debugger and the same result.

Comment: Have you tried to close a file before deleting?

Comment: `Unlock` pairs with `Lock`, `Close` (and `Dispose`) pairs with `new FileStream` (and `File.Open`).

Comment: `Unlock()` does not do what you think it does. Your `using() { ... }` block locks the file, you can delete it outside that.

Comment: reference and delete the file outside the using() your file stream holds it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your problem caused by the fact a file is still open when you call `File.Delete`.
Try to move the `File.Delete` call out of the `using` block:

```
using (var lockFile = new FileStream(lockFilePath, ...))
{
    ...
}
File.Delete(lockFilePath);
```

Or simply call `lockFile.Close` before `File.Delete`:

```
finally
{
    lockFile.Close();
    File.Delete(lockFilePath);
}
```

Comment: Darn, took me too long to write the answer from my phone :). +1

Comment: Will a close unlock it as well?

Comment: @user3791372 : That's what closing it is for :). `Close()` calls `Dispose()`, just like the `using` block

Comment: @user3791372 No doubt.

Comment: @stavm : "douche"? That sounds a bit mean.

Comment: @Visual Vincent no harm meant, +1.